# how to do percentage match between list of strings in apache lucene

Tags: java, lucene

Let's Assume I am having a list of Documents in Lucene index where i have configured Keywords/Phrases as like this.

```
Title: FaceBook 
Content: Associated list of rules, notification, facebook.
```

Here title is a field and content is a field.
now my input is

**this is a notification message from facebook**

so the result for the following message should be,

**no of hits: 2**

**Percentage Match: 100%** (Cause both the configured Keywords match Fully )

now my another input is,

**misconfiguration is notified**

so here configured was notification which has 12 characters .and in message is notified where only 6 characters is only matching so (6/12*100) which should 50% .

so i want a output like this 
Partial Match Occurred 
and the percentage match is 50%

Comment: You have tagged all three - solr, elastic & lucene . What are you actually using & what have you tried so far?

Comment: Right now I am using lucene . and i tried to calculate percentage match on basis of term query match, but that is not much helping.

Answer (score 3):

somehow my solution for the percentage match is this

```
public class lab1 {
  public static double similarity(String s1, String s2) {
    String longer = s1, shorter = s2;
    if (s1.length() < s2.length()) { // longer should always have greater length
      longer = s2; shorter = s1;
    }
    int longerLength = longer.length();
    if (longerLength == 0) { return 1.0; /* both strings are zero length */ }
    /* // If you have Apache Commons Text 
     // you can use it to calculate the edit distance:
    LevenshteinDistance levenshteinDistance = new LevenshteinDistance();
    return (longerLength - levenshteinDistance.apply(longer, shorter)) / (double) longerLength; */
    return (longerLength - editDistance(longer, shorter)) / (double) longerLength;

  }

  public static int editDistance(String s1, String s2) {
    s1 = s1.toLowerCase();
    s2 = s2.toLowerCase();

    int[] costs = new int[s2.length() + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= s1.length(); i++) {
      int lastValue = i;
      for (int j = 0; j <= s2.length(); j++) {
        if (i == 0)
          costs[j] = j;
        else {
          if (j > 0) {
            int newValue = costs[j - 1];
            if (s1.charAt(i - 1) != s2.charAt(j - 1))
              newValue = Math.min(Math.min(newValue, lastValue),
                  costs[j]) + 1;
            costs[j - 1] = lastValue;
            lastValue = newValue;
          }
        }
      }
      if (i > 0)
        costs[s2.length()] = lastValue;
    }
    return costs[s2.length()];
  }

  public static void printSimilarity(String s, String t) {
    System.out.println(String.format(
      "%.3f Percent is the similarity between \"%s\" and \"%s\"", similarity(s, t)*100, s, t));
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    printSimilarity("", "");
    printSimilarity("1234567890", "1");
    printSimilarity("1234567890", "123");
    printSimilarity("1234567890", "1234567");
    printSimilarity("1234567890", "1234567890");
    printSimilarity("1234567890", "1234567980");
    printSimilarity("47/2010", "472010");
    printSimilarity("47/2010", "472011");
    printSimilarity("47/2010", "AB.CDEF");
    printSimilarity("47/2010", "4B.CDEFG");
    printSimilarity("47/2010", "AB.CDEFG");
    printSimilarity("The quick fox jumped", "The jumped fox");
    printSimilarity("The quick fox jumped", "The fox");
    printSimilarity("kitten", "sitting");
  }

}
```